# Java: How can I add images from a file into a ResourceBundle?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, resourcebundle

I am trying to make a splitpane gui object in java as the one described in the link: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~jtbauer/cis3931/tutorial/ui/swing/example-swing/SplitPaneDemo.java

But I really don't understand this part:

```
try {
        imageResource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("imagenames");
        String imageListString = imageResource.getString("images");
        imageList = parseList(imageListString);
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        System.err.println("Can't find list of image names.");
        System.exit(-1);
}
```

So basically it is asking me to make a resourcebundle from a file called 'image names' that contains the list of images I want to use? I don't understand how resourcebundle works and the examples I have seen used online all involve it using objects or arrays. How can I use resourcebundle to get images from a file to use?

Comment: Maybe you should start by doing a quick [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&q=java+eclipse+resource+bundle&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii9pzrhKbWAhXFmpQKHS_wBJIQBQglKAA&biw=840&bih=885)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a property file "imagenames" that contains the key "images" with values separated by blanks " ".

```
images=image1name.png img2name.png img3name.png ...
```

You can see that in the parseList method you parse the string into array of names of images.

```
protected static Vector parseList(String theStringList) {
    Vector v = new Vector(10);
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(theStringList, " ");
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String image = tokenizer.nextToken();
            v.addElement(image);
        }
    return v;
    }
```

and e.g. in the SplitPaneDemo method:

```
// Set up the picture label and put it in a scroll pane
         currentImage = new ImageIcon("images/" + 
                     (String)imageList.firstElement());
```

you get the first image from "images" dir + image name from your images list.

i.e. `currentImage = new ImageIcon("images/image1name.png")`

in total, you should to create a dir, add your images, create the property file "imagenames" with the key "images" and `values = yourImgName1 yourImgName2` .... separated e.g. by blanks

```
images=yourImgName1 yourImgName2 ...
```

and use your example to get images from the dir.

How it works see
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file-with-a-resource-bundle.html

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-resourcebundle-example/